# Java: JTextField with JComboBox

Tags: swing

How do you go about creating a JTextfield with a drop down embedded into it? So you can use the drop down to select a value which will show up in the JTextfield. I am not looking for autocomplete but the ability to select and show values from combobox in the same textfield. For example a browser's url box and it can also act as a drop down showing urls that match it. I would like the drop down button to show up however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no specific reason of why you want to use `JTextField`, I suggest you to use an **editable JComboBox**. It is a combobox that you can type customized text on the top option field and also you have the ability of selecting the customized text and process it from combobox. Take a look at this example, it might be the solution that you are looking for: [Editable ComboBox with Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AfancyexampleofJComboBoxwithacustomrendererandeditor.htm)

Comment: ah didn't know that existed. thank you. i found an editable jcombobox as you suggested. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable